# Gender stereotypes

Tags: psychology, gender

Guys i am new in gender studies, but somethings is really puzzeling to me. [In Gender, nature, and Nurture](https://www.routledge.com/Gender-Nature-and-Nurture/Lippa/p/book/9780805853452) from Richard A. Lippa there are comment about role of gender stereotypes in making "typical male or female work in home at so on": in our culture - typical women should take care about children and man should make money.

How ever my question is: Do gender stereotypes are product of culture traditions and history of your society or do gender stereotypes main reason for roles differenciation by [genders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqEgsHGiK-s)?

Edited detail: it was mentioned that I underestimated how broad this theme actually is. So I decided to actually to prefer a Western culture point of view.

Comment: sorry guys but i am unfortunately new in this topic so i cant say more about it. Just to sum my question: do gender stereotypes make gender roles or does typical gender roles are or should they have reason behind that in culter (like i am man man because i can hunt down a bear).

Comment: This question is not framed within established models or practices of psychology and neuroscience and would seem to be off-topic here. This seems to lack any context of evolutionary biology and sex differences, it asks a binary cultural-tradition/stereotype question regarding "gender roles" which is naïve for lack of an underpinning in the broader context of the way animals have evolved to behave and their innate characteristics. I'd recommend that you read around the subject, looking at primate behaviour to give you context.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant Txn for comment. I actually didn't even think about an option that it might be of topic because I am a quite practicioner of Gothe line about not only knowing knowledge but applying too. So It didn't even cross my mind that it might be of topic. However you actually can think about it from nature nurture point of view and it might be add to  sociobiology.

Comment: Generally speaking, gender stereotypes  are created by society and cultural traditions which can sometimes involve historical or religious tradition. Who said women should stay at home, looking after the children while their husbands go out to work? Why not the other way round? There are many who do things the other way round, and some where both husband and wife go out while the children are in day care or night time childcare. These stereotypes often lead to prejudice and other societal issues.

Comment: While your question looks at the origins of gender stereotypes, the subject of gender stereotypes is huge and can fill textbooks. Because of this, your question is in need of some focus. As a suggestion, maybe you could focus the question on the Western cultural influences toward gender stereotypes? Maybe you want to look at Eastern cultural differences to how the Western culture looks at gender roles?

Comment: @Chris Rogers really appreciate it because eventhought I am reading the that mentioned book I am not still sure what the gender truelly is not mentioned gender stereotypes. I am not saying that gender stereotypes not existing - I was a victom of one (normal boys doesn't like dancing..);. Just gender stereotypes in that book are explained by defined by circle to me..

Comment: "What is gender" is another big subject in its own right which has a bearing on gender stereotypes. As the YouTube video you linked to in your question discusses, there is more awareness of gender fluidity and non-binary gendered communities. Start by asking yourself, "Which are you wanting to learn about first?". Then from there, look at what is not clear to you or confusing you about it. Then you can provide a more focused question which will be clearer and more easy to answer.

Comment: @Chris Rogers Thank you for your comments to my question. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question,  (from a social constructivist approach to gender stereotypes, and gender roles) both from "gender roles" and "culture". However, there are other approaches to conceptualizing gender in development that differ.

For example, a main feature of [Liben and Bigler’s (2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3181530) social constructivist orientation is its adherence to group membership as a guide to conceptualize the development of gendered attitudes & beliefs relating to self and others, moreover, in linking sex-typed characterizations of the self to attitudes about others.

**References**

Liben, L. S., Bigler, R. S., Ruble, D. N., Martin, C. L., & Powlishta, K. K. (2002). The Developmental Course of Gender Differentiation: Conceptualizing, Measuring, and Evaluating Constructs and Pathways. Monographs of the Society for Research in Child Development, 67(2), i–183. http://www.jstor.org/stable/3181530